# Python 2.7: if code block not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have tested out the following program, and there are no errors. But whenever I enter `"hangman"` it won't start the new block of `if` statement code named `"if response_2"`. Why is it not running it?

```
    response_2 = raw_input("What would you like to play? Hangman or Word Guess?")
    if response_2 == ("Hangman", "hangman"):
        print "Running Hangman..."
        print "Catching Criminals..."
        print "Building Gallows..."
        print "Getting that one song boy from Pirate's of the Carribean"
    elif response_2 == ("Word_Guess", "word_guess", "word guess", "Word Guess", "Word guess", "word Guess", "Word_guess", "word_Guess"):
        print "Not completed yet"
```

Comment: Please paste the code into the question. Links go bad over time, and where would that leave SO?

Comment: Your condition can **never** be `True`. Why would that block ever run?

Comment: It needs to be an "in", not an equality to the tuple. What's being entered isn't equivalent to it... It's a member of it.

Answer (score 8):

This is because you are *directly comparing* to the tuple with `==`, which will always give `False` as the `raw_input` gives a string, not a `tuple`. You need to check if any one of the responses is in the sequence. Do this with `in`:

```
if response in ('Hangman', 'hangman'):
```

Likewise with the similar comparison within the `elif`.

Comment: @The10thDoctor Great, glad I could help. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it after the grace period has passed? You can do it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so it turns green and stays green. Thank you.